# Carburizing Calculation

Tags: materials, solid-state-chemistry

The problem is stated as follows:
*The surface of a steel gear made of 1022 steel (0.22 wt% C) is to be gas-carburized at $927$ °C. Calculate the time necessary to increase the carbon content to 0.30 wt% at 0.030 in below the surface of the gear. Assume the carbon content of the surface to be 1.20 wt% and* $D_{927^{\circ}C}=1.28 \times 10^{-11}\frac{m^{2}}{s}$

The formula is $\frac{C_{s}-C_{x}}{C_{s}-C_{0}}=ERF(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{Dt}})$

The solution manual is setting $C_{x}=0.30$, but should it not be $C_{x}=0.30+0.22=0.52$, since the initial carbon content in the steel is $C_{0}=0.22$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

In the equation $C_x$ simply means the concentration at depth x. It does not mean the *change* of concentration. There is no need to add its initial concentration.

Besides, concentration cannot be linearly added. (Does adding a 1M solution to a 2M solution give 3M?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the analogy, but does this not mean that we are assuming that the initial carbon content is 0, and not 0.22? I am confused because the problem use the word "increase".

Comment: Nope. Its initial carbon content throughout the entire steel is 0.22wt%. You are not trying to increase it **by** 0.30wt% but increase it **to** 0.30wt%.